# Context evaluating as undefined in React Native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm attempting to create an Auth context file which, upon app load, checks if a user is signed in.

To do this, I'm using a 'helper' function which allows me to import the initialisation of the context and just build upon that with additional functions which authorise a user.

However, upon every app load, the Context is returning as 'undefined', and it says 'evaluating _useContext.trySignIn'.

For reference, here is my Context file:

```
import createDataContext from './createDataContext';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { navigate } from '../navigationRef';

import { Magic } from '@magic-sdk/react-native';
const m = new Magic('API_key');

const authReducer = (state, reducer) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const trySignIn = dispatch => async () => {
  const isLoggedIn = await m.user.isLoggedIn();

  if (isLoggedIn === true) {
    navigate('Dashboard');
  } else {
    navigate('loginFlow');
  }
};

export const { Provider, Context } = createDataContext (
  authReducer,
  { trySignIn },
  { isLoggedIn: null }
);
```

Here is my 'createDataContext' file:

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';

export default (reducer, actions, defaultValue) => {
  const Context = React.createContext();

  const Provider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaultValue);

    const boundActions = {};

    for (let key in actions) {
      boundActions[key] = actions[key].dispatch;
    }

    return (
      <Context.Provider value={{ state, ...boundActions }}>
        {children}
      </Context.Provider>
    )
  };

  return { Context, Provider }
};
```

Here is my navigation file:

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let navigator;

export const setNavigator = (nav) => {
  navigation = nav;
};

export const navigate = (routeName, params) => {
  navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName, params
    })
  );
};
```

And finally, here is my component attempting to use my context:

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { Context } from '../context/AuthContext';

const LoadingScreen = () => {

  const { trySignIn } = useContext(Context);

  useEffect(() => {
    trySignIn();
  }, [])

  return (
    <View style={styles.mainView}>
      <ActivityIndicator style={styles.indicator} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Can anyone see why my context would be returning as 'undefined' in my component?